# Windows 7 wireless auto-shut-off problem after boot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, power-management

I've been experiencing a strange problem with Windows 7 (64-bit) in that after booting up, the wireless is sometimes shut off by Windows (with a little announcement that pops up from the bottom-right-corner; sometimes two or three of these appear at the same time but usually only one).  If I don't click the "Dismiss" button quickly enough, I get disconnected and then have to re-enable my wireless NIC.

For web sites and other connection-less protocols, this is not a big deal, but with an SSH session (e.g., via PuTTY) it becomes a very big annoyance as I have to re-connect those as well.

My laptop is connected to AC power, and the power management is set to run in high-performance mode with AC.

Any suggestions about what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use wireless drivers, it could potentially be them failing. Make sure they are updated to the latest version. If you wireless card is not built in, also make sure its connected properly

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion.  My wireless drivers are already up-to-date, including Windows 7 itself (which I keep updated somewhat regularly).  The wireless hardware is built-in (integrated).

Comment: Is this a laptop? If so, what brand?

Comment: Yes, it's a laptop.  It's one of those custom built all-Intel ones (I got tired of the nonsense with major vendors including an endless stream of pop-ups and weird drivers that include enormous GUIs just to display a fancy on/off switch wrapped up in some vendor's logo that hog all spare resources and slow everything down, and have found this to be a good solution).  So, the wireless B/G/N NIC is also made by Intel (along with the motherboard, CPU, etc.).  I suspect this is a Windows 7 function that I'm dealing with as I've seen this on other laptops with different brands of components.

Comment: This may help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-keeps-disconnecting-from-laptop-windows-7/1338d169-9fcc-4a05-87e8-60e0f1aa0bdf

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a try (and flag this as "answered" for now).

Comment: Great. Hope I have provided at least some knowledge :)

Comment: I haven't looked at the IEEE Authentication stuff at all, but one I'm finished with this long PuTTY session (GNU Screen isn't installed on the remote box yet) I'll be looking into this.  I'm optimistic because this is something I haven't tried and it also appears to be a solution for some other people.